# Unable to match spaces in awk if they have different length (During Parsing)

Tags: awk

I'm using awk (not supported GAWK).

I'm trying to parse a file.  (I couldn't format the input and output in the question, If some one can format them, please support)

The input file as shown:-

```
Selc   PR  Seq     Salary   Level     Rate  
    2  1x     3x   360020   EXPERT   
       1      2    962010   EXPERT   
       1      5    269050   EXPERT   
       1      6    269060   EXPERT   
   68  1      1    360020   EXPERT   
       1      2    962010   EXPERT   
       1      6    269060   EXPERT   
2      7      7    360020   EXPERT      
  962  1      2    169820   BEGINNER  146
       1      3    267170   BEGINNER  146
       1      1    169810   EXPERT    148
 1005  1      1    360020   EXPERT   
       1      2    962010   EXPERT   
       1      3    962010   EXPERT   
END
```

The code is as shown:-

```
        BEGIN {
         Salarylit("Selc,PR,Seq,Salary,Level,Rate",array,",");
         print_array(array)
      }
  /^Selc   PR  Seq  Salary       Level  Rate/ { 
             getline
             array[1]=trim_blank(substr($0,1,5))  #Selc
             array[2]=trim_blank(substr($0,8,4))  #PR
             array[3]=trim_blank(substr($0,14,4)) #Seq
             array[4]=trim_blank(substr($0,20,7)) #Salary
             array[5]=trim_blank(substr($0,29,6)) #Level
             array[6]=trim_blank(substr($0,37,4)) #Rate
             getline
           }
  /^ /   {if(NF!=0)
                {
             print_array(array)
             array[2]=trim_blank(substr($0,8,4)) #SalaryID
             array[3]=trim_blank(substr($0,14,4)) #Seq
             array[4]=trim_blank(substr($0,20,7)) #Salary
             array[5]=trim_blank(substr($0,29,6)) #Level
             array[6]=trim_blank(substr($0,37,4)) #Rate
                }
             }

function print_array(array)
{
    printf("%-6s", array[1])
    printf("%-5s", array[2])
    printf("%-5s", array[3])
    printf("%-8s", array[4])
    printf("%-7s", array[5])
    printf("%-5s", array[6])
    printf("\n");
}

function trim_blank(str){
#trim will remove the SalaryACE & TAB at begining or end of str
  blk=" "
  tab="\t"
  while(1){
    if((substr(str,1,1)==blk)||(substr(str,1,1)==tab)) {str=substr(str,2,(length(str)-1))}
    else if((substr(str,length(str),1)==blk)||(substr(str,length(str),1)==tab)) {str=substr(str,1,(length(str)-1))}
    else {return str}
    }
}
```

The output should be as shown:-

```
Selc   PR  Seq     Salary   Level     Rate  
2      1x     3x   360020   EXPERT   
2      1      2    962010   EXPERT   
2      1      5    269050   EXPERT   
2      1      6    269060   EXPERT   
68     1      1    360020   EXPERT   
68     1      2    962010   EXPERT   
68     1      6    269060   EXPERT   
2      7      7    360020   EXPERT      
962    1      2    169820   BEGINNER  146
962    1      3    267170   BEGINNER  146
962    1      1    169810   EXPERT    148
1005   1      1    360020   EXPERT   
1005   1      2    962010   EXPERT   
1005   1      3    962010   EXPERT
```

Comment: You specifically said in your question that you don't have access to gawk (`I'm using awk (not supported GAWK).`) and then accepted an answer that will only work in gawk,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **GNU** awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="7 5 7 9 10 4"}
     {
       # remove leading and trailing spaces from every field
       for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {gsub(/^ +| +$/, "", $i)}

       # if $1 is empty use previous content
       if($1==""){$1=c1}

       # save current content
       c1=$1

       printf("%-7s%-5s%-7s%-9s%-10s%-4s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)
     }' file
```

Output:

```
Selc   PR   Seq    Salary   Level     Rate
2      1x   3x     360020   EXPERT        
2      1    2      962010   EXPERT        
2      1    5      269050   EXPERT        
2      1    6      269060   EXPERT        
68     1    1      360020   EXPERT        
68     1    2      962010   EXPERT        
68     1    6      269060   EXPERT        
2      7    7      360020   EXPERT        
962    1    2      169820   BEGINNER  146 
962    1    3      267170   BEGINNER  146 
962    1    1      169810   EXPERT    148 
1005   1    1      360020   EXPERT        
1005   1    2      962010   EXPERT        
1005   1    3      962010   EXPERT        
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="" }
NR==1 {
    sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    hdr = $0
    while ( match(hdr,/[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/) ) {
        wids[++nf] = RLENGTH
        hdr = substr(hdr,1+RLENGTH)
    }
    nf++
}
{
    delete vals

    for (i=1; i<nf; i++) {
        vals[i] = substr($0,1,wids[i])
        $0 = substr($0,1+wids[i])
    }
    vals[nf] = $0

    for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
        val = ( (i==1) && (vals[i]~/^[[:space:]]*$/) ? prev[i] : vals[i] )
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",val)
        wid = ( i < nf ? wids[i] : length(val) )

        printf "%-*s%s", wid, val, (i<nf ? OFS : ORS)

        prev[i] = val
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Selc   PR  Seq     Salary   Level     Rate
2      1x  3x      360020   EXPERT
2      1   2       962010   EXPERT
2      1   5       269050   EXPERT
2      1   6       269060   EXPERT
68     1   1       360020   EXPERT
68     1   2       962010   EXPERT
68     1   6       269060   EXPERT
2      7   7       360020   EXPERT
962    1   2       169820   BEGINNER  146
962    1   3       267170   BEGINNER  146
962    1   1       169810   EXPERT    148
1005   1   1       360020   EXPERT
1005   1   2       962010   EXPERT
1005   1   3       962010   EXPERT
```